# Compare 2 Datasets and get differences in Spark-Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have a Dataset from Audit Table which is 24 hrs Old (Ds1) and current Day Changes as of Now (Ds2)

How to get differences of values (individual cells) in a 3rd - DiffDs

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: started try trying - https://finraos.github.io/MegaSparkDiff/#

Comment: The two dataset have the same schema?

Comment: Yup sand schema

Answer (score 1):

If the two dataset have the same schema you can do

```
val delta = ds2.except(ds1)
```

that from the doc `Returns a new Dataset containing rows in this Dataset but not in another Dataset`.

This will be the delta of the newest record and the oldest record.

If the schema of the dataset are different in my opinion all ds2 are the difference.

But this how you say on the comment return the difference on the entire Row.

I think that, to extract the cell difference you need to do something like this:

```
val diff = ds1.union(ds2).distinct() //that contains all different record
diff.rdd.keyBy(r(key_index_here)).groupByKey(a_simple_function_that_compute_column_difference)
```

Now you have to write a function that compute the difference in terms of cell from a sequence of Row that are grouped by a key.

Comment: How to get to individual cell level? Loop through all columns